# Flatpickr - Can't change format when to english format when updating input field.

Tags: javascript, flatpickr

```
        new flatPickr(flatPicker,
            {
                nextArrow: '<svg class="icon icon-arrow-right"><use xlink:href="/dist/assets/svg-definition/symbol-defs.svg#icon-arrow-right"></use></svg>',
                prevArrow: '<svg class="icon icon-arrow-left"><use xlink:href="/dist/assets/svg-definition/symbol-defs.svg#icon-arrow-left"></use></svg>',

                // Date format
                altInput: true,
                altFormat: 'd-m-Y'
            }
        );
```

I'm trying to use the altFormat to change the value of the date so that it is in the english DD/MM/YYYY format rather than the american format.

I felt that setting the alTformat to the above would have done this. Is there something that I am missing.

The html of my element looks like this.

```
            <div class="form__date-picker form__placeholder">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.DateOfBirth, StringFormats.ProfileDateTimeFormat, new { 
                    @class = "form__input flatpickr", 
                    placeholder = "Date of birth"
                })
                <svg class="icon icon-calendar">
                    <use xlink:href="/dist/assets/svg-definition/symbol-defs.svg#icon-calendar"></use>
                </svg>        
            </div>
```

Please let me know if there is any information that I have missed you need.

Comment: Are you getting any error? setting `altInput` and `altFormat` should have worked, here is a working example https://jsbin.com/yetikad/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Getting no errors which is frustrating